# edit name after login user

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Angular app where user can login with his email and password. so I need when current user connected showing in (app.component.html) by using localStorage. I get all the information from a data base mysql.

code :

**auth.service.ts:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor() { }


  getUserDetails() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('userData')){
      return localStorage.getItem('userData')
    }else{
      return null
    }
    
  }
  setDataInLocalStorage(variableName, data) {
      localStorage.setItem(variableName, data);
  }
  getToken() {
      return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
  clearStorage() {
      localStorage.clear();
  }
  
  
}
```

Comment: since you already stored user data in localstorage, you can get data from localStorage, and bind it to html component or directly bind the data (username) when you already get response from API

Comment: @hafizihamid hot to do that ??

Answer (score 1):

Update

```
getUserDetails() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('userData')) {
        return localStorage.getItem('userData');
    } else {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

To

```
getUserDetails(variableName) {
    return localStorage.getItem(variableName);
}
```